# HTML / PHP to list attached drives, used space, and available space

Tags: php, html, linux, raspberry-pi

I currently have a website that hosts some files. I want to try and display on it the attached drives, their capacity, and free space.  I know in linux, the command

```
df -H
```

does this very well. I don't know how to display the output on my website. I have discovered this command as well:

```
$df = disk_total_space("/dev/md0/");
echo $df;
```

but the result is nothing displayed. Anyone ever done anything like this before or does anyone see anything wrong with what I tried?

By the way, this is all being performed from my raspberry pi on debian.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always parse the output of `df -aTh`:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    echo shell_exec("df -aTh");
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks!